# How to test non-public methods?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, junit, scalatest

I am learning Scala and wrote `Email` class which looks like:

```scala
class Email(emailConfigName: String) {
  private val emailConfig = ConfigFactory.load(emailConfigName) getConfig ("email")

  def notifySupportForTenant(symbolicName: String) {
    val emailMessage: Message = constructEmailMessage(symbolicName)
    Transport.send(emailMessage)
  }

  def constructEmailMessage(symbolicName: String): Message = {
    val message = createMessage(emailConfig getString ("shn.mail.smtp.host"))
    message setFrom (new InternetAddress(emailConfig getString ("shn.mail.from")))
    // todo: should come from API (sent by client)
    message setSentDate (new Date())
    message setSubject (emailConfig getString ("shn.mail.subject") replace("TENANT_ID", symbolicName))
    message setContent(emailConfig getString ("shn.mail.body"), "text/html")
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, getMessageRecipients(emailConfig getString ("shn.mail.recipient")))
    message
  }

  private def createMessage(smtpHost: String): Message = {
    val properties = new Properties()
    properties put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost)
    val session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null)
    return new MimeMessage(session)
  }

  private def getMessageRecipients(recipient: String): Array[Address] = {
    // had to do the asInstanceOf[...] call here to make scala happy
    val addressArray = buildInternetAddressArray(recipient).asInstanceOf[Array[Address]]
    if ((addressArray != null) && (addressArray.length > 0)) addressArray
    else
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("no recipients found to send email")
  }

  private def buildInternetAddressArray(address: String): Array[InternetAddress] = {
    // could test for a null or blank String but I'm letting parse just throw an exception
    return InternetAddress.parse(address)
  }
}
```

I want to test this class's public API, `notifySupportForTenant` but this is not good for unit test since it also calls `Transport.send(emailMessage)` which will send the email.

All I am interested in testing if the message is constructed correctly. Which means I need to test `constructEmailMessage`.

In order to test this, I had to make this `public` which is also exposed as public interface, which I do not prefer. What can I do?

Comment: have you tried reflection?

Comment: One common way out is to make the private methods package-private, and then put the tests in the same package.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test a class that has private methods, fields or inner classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-to-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes)

Answer (score 6):

In traditional OO programming methods are often made private so that they cannot be called by the outside and corrupt the state of the instance. Once your method is really a function without side-effects (as `constructEmailMessage` appears to be), there really isn't a reason to make it private.

As your purpose is to learn `scala`, I would encourage you to adopt a functional style operating on immutable data as much as possible, because it alleviates a lot of the reasons OO programming favors protected encapsulations.

Comment: Agreed!  The `Email` class sounds like the perfect thing to make into a `case class`!

Comment: Off the top of my head, 2 reasons for wanting to keep a function private: 1) you don't wan't to clutter the public API, 2) it is a helper function that you want to be able to freely refactor / rename without worrying about breaking client software. I'd pref Seth Tissue's recommendation and scope the method to `private[mypackage] def createMesssage(...`

Comment: You can achieve both 1 & 2 by putting the public API in a trait, leaving your implementation to keep methods public (as long as they're stateless & idempotent). If you are worried about the API surface, package private still leaves the next maintainer of your package to accidentally use your private method. Personally, I prefer splitting public API and implementation as it is more explicit. Either works, tho

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) library!

```
import org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox

val email = new Email("lalala@mail.com")
val expected = new Message(...)
val smtpHost = "127.0.0.1"

val actual = Whitebox.invokeMethod(email, "createMessage", smtpHost).asInstanceOf[Message]

assert(actual = expected)
```

This library also helpful for *mocking* private methods, but if you don't need its entire power for you tasks you can use reflection as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34658/1591139).